# Why in the 70s and 80s was the United Kingdom called Great Britain in the international naming conventions?

Tags: united-kingdom

I am not sure whether this is the right group for this question because it is about the recent past. But I didn't find a more suitable forum.

Checking old articles and documents from my country I saw that everywhere the United Kingdom was called Great Britain, but as far as I know the name of the UK was established 2 centuries ago.
Traveling to other countries I saw also a lot of document forms from the 1990s and even early the 2000s referring to Great Britain. Also some drop down boxes in old software apps had that name.
Actually the name stuck also in the UK because I remember old cars with the international sticker with the GB label.

Why did the old name stick for so long? When did it actually disappear from the international naming conventions?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: I recall reading that this was because Ukraine had gotten the UK 2-letter code by the rules for generating code, and the UK was given GB as next-best. I don't recall where, unfortunately, or I'd make it an answer.

Comment: I think the answer may well be related to those car stickers. Before people started using URLs, car stickers were one common way to encounter abbreviations for foreign countries. These stickers and abbreviations have also almost disappeared now, or at least (when integrated into license plates) have become much smaller

Comment: 'Great Britain' isn't 'the old name'. [This website](https://www.dictionary.com/e/great-britain-vs-uk-vs-england/) explains that it is a geographical term, whereas 'United Kingdom' is a political term.

Comment: I can only assume The Troubles had something to do with the de-emphasis of GB and the emphasis of UK. The JANET domain naming system proposed "UK" as a top-level domain in 1984, as opposed to ISO 3166's "GB" (2nd version as late as 1981).  The original code proposed in RFC 1591 (the basis of DNS TLDs) was .gb but the JANET version was the one used.

Comment: @KateBunting "Great Britain", despite any Internet-era pedagogical materials you may find, is indeed the _older_ name, as this was the name used in the [1707 Acts of Union](https://www.rct.uk/collection/1142244/articles-of-union-between-england-and-scotland-1706)

Comment: The terminology went from being "a united Kingdom" in 1707 to "the United Kingdom" in the 1800 Union with Ireland act.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of one of these "old articles and documents"? My understanding from the Brits I know is that these terms all have quite specific defined meanings, so without the context of the references being made, its nearly impossible to talk about this intelligently.

Comment: @Spencer - I was interpreting 'the old name' as meaning 'an obsolete name', which it isn't.

Comment: @MarkOlson Ukraine recieved UA because UK was reserved on request of the United Kingdom in 1974 (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes).

Comment: @MarkOlson: Ukraine wasn't an independent country until 1991, though.

Comment: [According to Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=United+Kingdom%2CGreat+Britain&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), "United Kingdom" has been the more popular term since 1948.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Great Britain** was the official name of the [Kingdom of Great Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Great_Britain) (1707-05-01 to 1800-12-31) and consisted of the Kingdoms of England (which included Wales) and Scottland. Thus the whole island of [Great Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain) formed one Kingdom.

With the [Act of Union (Ireland) 1800](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/aip/Geo3/40/38), the kingdoms of Great Britain and Ireland were united into one kingdom.

> That it be first article of the union of the kingdoms of Great Britain and Ireland, that the said kingdoms of Great Britain and Ireland shall, upon the first day of January, which shall be in the year of our lord one thousand eight hundred and one, and for ever, be united into one kingdom, by the name of “**the united kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland**,” and ... shall be such as his Majesty by his royal proclamation under the great seal of the **united kingdom** shall be pleased to appoint.

Since the names of countries, nationalities, and languages are proper nouns, the consistent use of **united kingdom** (and not **United Kingdom**) within the act implies that the term was not intended to be used as an *official short* name.

International treaties, signed afterwords, still used *Great Britain* in the same way as *France* was used for the French Republic (i.e. in a geographical sense).

- Final Act of the Congress of Vienna (1815-06-09)

  - His Majesty the King of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland:
  - ART. XVII. Austria, Russia, Great Britain, and France, guarantee, ...
  - and the Kings of Great Britain and Prussia,
- International Convention With respect to the Circulation of Motor Vehicles, signed at Paris, the 11th October 1909

  - His Majesty the King of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland and of the British Dominions beyond the Seas, Emperor of India;
  - For Great Britain :
  - Great Britain and Ireland, GB;
- League of Nations Passport Conference, Geneva, 1926-05-18

  - Mr. Haldane PORTER (**Great Britain**) said that, when a foreigner had to register with police in the **United Kingdom**, ...

Here it becomes apparent that a different terminology is being used depending from where it is being use (inside or outside of the United Kingdom).

> [Treason Felony Act 1848](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/11-12/12)
> If any person whatsoever shall, within the **United Kingdom** or without, compass, imagine, invent, devise, or intend to deprive or depose our Most Gracious Lady the Queen, from the style, honour, or royal name of the imperial crown of the **United Kingdom**, or of any other of her Majesty’s dominions and countries, or to levy war against her Majesty, within any part of the **United Kingdom**, ...

The question arises why, if parlament uses **United Kingdom** (since at least 1848) why is *Great Britain* then used in the Motor Vehicles convention of 1909 where the GB car shield was introduced?

It would seem that, for whatever reason, the British goverment preferred that *Great Britain* should be used in an international context.

It may be that the British goverment thought having the word 'Britain' in the name was better, while inside Britain the term **United Kingdom** was commonly used.

The regulation page of this passport, issued 1935, would support this view:

[image]

---

> When did it actually disappear from the international naming conventions?

ISO 3166-2:GB is the entry for the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland in ISO 3166-2.

- UK was [exceptionally reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Exceptional_reservations) on request of the United Kingdom lest UK be used for any other country in 1974. Its main usage is the .uk internet ccTLD.

> [.gb is a reserved Internet country code top-level domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.gb) (ccTLD) for the United Kingdom, derived from Great Britain.
> The domain was introduced with RFC 920 in October 1984 that set out the creation of ccTLD generally using country codes derived from the corresponding two-letter code in the ISO 3166-1 list. However, the .uk domain had been created separately a few months before the compilation of this list [1985-07-24]. Consequently, .gb was never widely used. It is no longer possible to register under this domain.

As far as the vehicle distinguishing sign is concerned, the replacement of "GB" with "UK" came into effect on 2021-09-28.

> [Convention on Road Traffic Vienna, 8 November 1968: UNITED KINGDOM OF GREAT BRITAIN AND NORTHERN IRELAND: NOTIFICATION UNDER ARTICLE 45 (4).](https://treaties.un.org/doc/Publication/CN/2021/CN.207.2021-Eng.pdf) (PDF)
> The Secretary-General of the United Nations, acting in his capacity as depositary, communicates the following:
>
> On 28 June 2021, the Secretary-General received from the Government of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, in accordance with Article 45 (4) and Annex 3 of the Convention, a notification stating that the United Kingdom is changing the distinguishing sign that it had previously selected for display in international traffic on vehicles registered in the United Kingdom, from “GB” to “UK”, and that “this change will apply only to the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, and will not extend to any territories for the international relations of which the United Kingdom is responsible”.
>
> The change in the United Kingdom’s distinguishing sign will take effect three months after the deposit of this notification, i.e., on **28 September 2021**, in accordance with Article 54 (4) of the Convention.

---

**Sources**:

- [Kingdom of Great Britain - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Great_Britain)

  - [Great Britain - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain)
- [Act of Union (Ireland) 1800](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/aip/Geo3/40/38)
- [Treason Felony Act 1848](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/11-12/12)

  - An Act for the better Security of the Crown and Government of the United Kingdom

Comment: All this does is prove we're talking about less-formal references...it seems some time in the early 80's people stopped emphasizing the "Great Britain" part of the name and emphasizing the "United Kingdom" part.

Comment: @Spencer It may be that the British goverment thought having the word 'Britain' in the name was  better (or they didn't give the matter any thought at all).

Comment: Yes, I think that's the key....I want to blame it on Thatcher because of the timing (the Troubles+Falklands war) but it's pure speculation.

Comment: @MarkJohnson +1  I suspect that in the 80s, after decades of decline, our government favoured the cachet of having 'Great' in the name.  Similar to the way 'Rover Group' was used to disguise the decline of 'British Leyland', back then.

Comment: @DaveGremlin And yet, the term *Great Britain* has been used as a short name, in many different languages (in French: *Grande-Bretagne* ; in German: *Großbritannien*), for more than 120 years.

Comment: Within the British Isles the Republic of Ireland is, in certain contexts, sometimes referred to as "the Republic", and the meaning is understood. If one were to say "the Republic" in France or Italy it would be assumed one was talking about France or Italy. There are many Republics, there are also Peoples Republic of China, the Islamic Republic of Iran and the Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan. United Kingdom is not really a name but a description of what Great Britain and Noirthern Ireland, collectively, is.

Comment: @davidlol And within Ireland, 'the Republic' is often called 'the State'. [Transit (including Transfer Visa) Advice - Immigration Service Delivery](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/) *In all other situations you will need permission to enter **the State** (you will need to have the appropriate Irish entry visa if you are visa required for entry to Ireland)*

Comment: It appears that Parliament was using "United Kingdom" by itself in the ([long](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/59-60/14/contents/enacted)) names of acts it passed as early as 1801.

Answer (score -2):

A complete answer is given [here](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/blog/whats-the-difference-between-uk-britain-and-british-isles#:~:text=Great%20Britain%20is%20the%20official,you%20see%20all%20too%20often.):

UK and GB are two different notions, since UK also contains Northern Ireland, while GB does not.

Comment: Yet the Great Britain Olympic team includes Northern Ireland athletes as well as Scotland and Wales. And has for decades well before the “Team GB” branding.